# Display controller variable on a Laravel blade using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

In my laravel app, I have a div on a blade to display total number of daily orders.

```
<div class="row mt-3" id="shopify_row1">
        <div class="col-md-2" id="shopify_widget1">
            <div class="jumbotron bg-dark text-white">
                <img class="img-fluid pull-left" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-2092/100/social-35-512.png" width="32" height="32">
                <h6 class="text-secondary mt-2 px-4">Shopify</h6>
                <hr class="border border-white">
                <h5 class="text-white">Total Orders</h5>
                <span class="tot_o" id="tot_o">{{ $tot_o }}</span> 
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I get this `$tot_o` via controller.

Following is my `index()` in the controller

```
if($request->has('selected_date')){
                $selected_date=$request->selected_date;
                $url = "https://MYAPIKEY@MYSTORE.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/orders/count.json?status=any&created_at_max=".$selected_date."";
            }else{
                $selected_date = date('Y-m-d');
                $url = "https://MYAPIKEY@MYSTORE.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/orders/count.json?status=any&created_at_min=".$selected_date."";
            }
            $curl = curl_init( $url );
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            $result_1 = json_decode($json_response, TRUE);
            $tot_o = $result_1['count'];
  return view('dashboard.index', ['sum' => $sum, 
                'tot_o' => $tot_o]);
```

Now I'm trying to implement a date picker, so does the value of $tot_o should be changed according to the picked date, on change.

This is my date picker.

```
<td>
      <input id="date" class="date form-control" type="date">
</td>
```

And this is my JavaScript.

```
<script>
        $(document).on('change', '#date', function (e) {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : '/home',
            data : {selected_date : $('#date').val()},
            success:function(data){

            $('#tot_o').empty(); 
            var total_orders = JSON.parse("{{ json_encode($tot_o) }}")
            console.log(total_orders);

            },
            timeout:10000
        });

    });    
    </script>
```

But here when I console.log my output it always gives me 0, even though the total is greater than the 0...

How can I correct my JS to display the value inside the `<span class="tot_o" id="tot_o"></span>` correctly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the controller AJAX

```
return response()->json([
    'tot_o' => $tot_o
]);
```

So in AJAX

```
success:function(data){
    var total_orders = data.tot_o;
    $('#tot_o').text(total_orders);
},
```

Span should be (`id="tot_o"`)

```
<span class="tot_o" id="tot_o"></span>
```

You can use `.text()` or `.html()` to write data

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I do not have an ajax on my controller, I'm returning the view with an arrays

Comment: @nikamatahukamuko **In the controller AJAX**, this is for controller funtion of AJAX. `/home`

Comment: I'm really sorry , I still don't understand it, could you please edit your answer with the expected controller...

Comment: Where is this method? `type: 'GET',
            url : '/home',` . End point of this

Comment: it's in my web.php,Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home'); and the method is under the index() of HomeController

Comment: in that function return should be `response()->json([]);`

Comment: But I'm returning a view... return view('dashboard.index', ['sum' => $sum, 
                'tot_o' => $tot_o]);

Comment: You cannot return the view and data at the same time—either one of these. Or define another function to get `tot_o`  value

Comment: okay, then how to return to the view from the controller...

Comment: This is working! thank you for your patience and the support!

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, write this:

```php
if($request->ajax()) {
    return response(['total_order'=> $tot_o],200);
}
```

In ajax request's success callback:

```js
$('#tot_o').text(ordertotal_orders);
```

Finally, add an id named `tot_o` to the span element:

```html
<span class="tot_o" id="tot_o"></span>
```